# Tower of Hanoi, problem with understanding the code

Tags: python

I have a problem with understanding this code.

code:

```
def hanoi(n,  A,  B,  C) :
   ' ' ' n - number of discs
   A - initial stick
   B - Middle stick
   C - Goal stick ' ' '

   if n > 0:
      hanoi(n - 1,  A,  C,  B)
      print('Disc',  n,  'from',  A,  'to',  C)
      hanoi(n - 1, B, A,  C)

hanoi(3, 'A', 'B', 'C')
```

When I use debugger I see in if loop, the control flow first checks the if condition, and after that it goes down in `hanoi(n - 1,  A,  C,  B)`, and when it executes that for the first time, It does it again three more times, instead to going on `print('disc',  n,  'from',  A,  'on',  C)`. I can't figure it out why it is doing that, and what kind of rules it uses for doing this. I working in IDLE environment.

Here is results of compiled program:

```
Disc 1 from A on C
Disc 2 from A to B
Disc 1 from C to B
Disc 3 form A to C
Disc 1 from B to A
Disc 2 from B to C
Disc 1 from A to C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because

```py
hanoi(n - 1, A, C, B)
#is before
print(...)
```

So it will destack before printing every subchild

Switch those two lines like

```py
print('Disc',  n,  'from',  A,  'to',  C)
hanoi(n - 1,  A,  C,  B)
hanoi(n - 1, B, A,  C)
```

And the code works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You must understand the implications of the code flow going down a branch such as `hanoi(n - 1,  A,  C,  B)` . That statement is *before* the print statement, and makes a recursive call to the function in a lower stack. The lower stack *must* be evaluated completely before you can proceed  further with the print statement.

The issue here is that you may find it hard to visualize "lower stacks" and recursion in a simple IDE. Here is a pythontutor visualization for the same. [link](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20hanoi%28n,%20%20A,%20%20B,%20%20C%29%20%3A%0A%20%20%20'''%20n%20-%20number%20of%20discs%0A%20%20%20A%20-%20initial%20stick%0A%20%20%20B%20-%20Middle%20stick%0A%20%20%20C%20-%20Goal%20stick%20'''%0A%0A%20%20%20if%20n%20%3E%200%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20hanoi%28n%20-%201,%20%20A,%20%20C,%20%20B%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28'Disc',%20%20n,%20%20'from',%20%20A,%20%20'to',%20%20C%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20hanoi%28n%20-%201,%20B,%20A,%20%20C%29%0A%0Ahanoi%283,%20'A',%20'B',%20'C'%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Bottom line though: The `print` statement did not execute simply because the control flow/code flow never encountered the `print` statement, and branched off to a lower stack because of the recursive call. The `print` happens exactly when it's supposed to, because that's how the code is written.